# getting undefined while sending http post method

Tags: angularjs

I am Passing my user information http angularjs. backend code is PHP
As I am the beginner I am searching lot for this Issue. and tried a lot methods since 2 days but I couldn't find the reason, and how to fix it?. it may be simple but I couldn't find.

1.I am posting my http post request in angularJS I have been debugged the value which I will send is

**Debugging value are as follow:**
serializedParams:"send_id=78&send_name=Douby&send_phone=4528&send_status=Due"

url: "insert.php?send_id=78&send_name=Douby&send_phone=4528&send_status=Due"
result: undefined

I think the url is correct. but the result is undefined

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("booking", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.paidops = ["Paid", "Due"];
  $scope.value = "ADD";
  $scope.insertvalues = function() {
    alert($scope.id + ' , ' +
      $scope.name + ' ,' + $scope.phone +
      ' , ' + $scope.status);
    alert($scope.name);
    var Indata = {
      'send_id': $scope.id,
      'send_name': $scope.name,
      'send_phone': $scope.phone,
      'send_status': $scope.status
    };
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'insert.php',
      params: Indata,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    }, function(response) {
      alert(response);

    });
  }
});
```

In PHP I am getting data like this way:

```
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "", "ticket_booking");
     if($connect === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
    if(count(array($data)) > 0)  
     
     {  
      $id_received = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->send_id);
     $name_received = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->send_name);
     $phone_received = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->send_phone);
     $status_received = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->send_status);
          $btnname_received = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->send_btnName);
    if($btnname_received == 'ADD'){
          $query = "INSERT INTO society_tour(id,name, phone, status) VALUES ('$id_received','$name_received', '$phone_received','$status_received')";  
          if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
          {  
               echo "Data Inserted...";  
          }  
          else  
          {  
               echo 'Error';  
          }  
         }
     ?>
```

Comment: need php part than handle this. We can't answer like this. For instance I see you do a POST but pass the value in the query string, are you sure you're reading the query string on the php side and not the request body ? (request body should be "data" parameters in angularJS from a 4 years old memory)

Comment: @Walfrat I have added my PHP code. . pls look at it. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure about the PHP part, but as you have `json_decode` in PHP, its safe to assume that PHP expects a JSON `content-type`

If so, here is how to post data to a url

```
var postUrl = 'insert.php'; // please check whether the url is correct
var dto = {
  'send_id': $scope.id,
  'send_name': $scope.name,
  'send_phone': $scope.phone,
  'send_status': $scope.status
};
$http({
  url: postUrl,
  method: 'POST',
  data: dto,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
//...
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is giving the data but the data is with escape character . .like  {"data":" string(74) \"{\"send_id\":\"45\",\"send_name\":\"Podhy\",\"send_phone\":125,\"send_status\":\"Paid\"} In my PHP data is null. I have added my php full  code.Is it this escape character is the reason I didn't get the data in  PHP?

Comment: I'm not sure that the JSON.stringify is necessary, @Pavi_Web did you try with `data:dto` simply ?

Comment: Thanks It is working now!! instead of data: JSON.stringify(dto)  just tried data:dto      Thanks @Naveen ,@Walfrat

Comment: Updated answer... Havent used angularjs for a bit